# T-SQL Reconcile Bin Qty's in ERP System

Tags: sql-server, compare

I have been tasked with coming up with a way to auto identify inventory transfers before Physical Inventory for my company. 
I have been trying to see if I can use SQL to solve this issue.  It is easier to show what I am trying to accomplish then explain so..
Here is some Sample Data you can use to see what I am trying to create. The Third table Transfers Needed and is only for reference since I would like a statement that spits the info from the two tables out in that format

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Adjustments_in') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Adjustments_in;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Adjustments_out') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Adjustments_out;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TransfersNeeded') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TransfersNeeded; 

CREATE TABLE #Adjustments_in
(
  ItemNumber VARCHAR(20) ,
  Bin VARCHAR(10) ,
  GPQty INT ,
  CountedQty INT ,
  AdjustmentQty INT
);

INSERT  INTO #Adjustments_in
    ( ItemNumber ,
      Bin ,
      GPQty ,
      CountedQty ,
      AdjustmentQty
    )
 VALUES  ( '850-001-003' , -- ItemNumber - varchar(20)
      'Rework' , -- Bin - varchar(10)
      0 , -- GPQty - int
      50 , -- CountedQty - int
      50  -- AdjustmentQty - int
    );

CREATE TABLE #Adjustments_out
(
  ItemNumber VARCHAR(20) ,
  Bin VARCHAR(10) ,
  GPQty INT ,
  CountedQty INT ,
  AdjustmentQty INT
);
INSERT  INTO #Adjustments_out
    ( ItemNumber ,
      Bin ,
      GPQty ,
      CountedQty ,
      AdjustmentQty
    )
VALUES  ( '850-001-003' , -- ItemNumber - varchar(20)
      '10.01.02' , -- Bin - varchar(10)
      25 , -- GPQty - int
      0 , -- CountedQty - int
      25  -- AdjustmentQty - int
    );

INSERT  INTO #Adjustments_out
    ( ItemNumber ,
      Bin ,
      GPQty ,
      CountedQty ,
      AdjustmentQty
    )
VALUES  ( '850-001-003' , -- ItemNumber - varchar(20)
      '14.01.12' , -- Bin - varchar(10)
      25 , -- GPQty - int
      0 , -- CountedQty - int
      25  -- AdjustmentQty - int
    );



CREATE TABLE #TransfersNeeded
(
  ItemNumber VARCHAR(20) ,
  FromBin VARCHAR(10) ,
  ToBin VARCHAR(10) ,
  Qty INT
 );


INSERT  INTO #TransfersNeeded
    ( ItemNumber ,
      FromBin ,
      ToBin ,
      Qty
    )
VALUES  ( '850-001-003' , -- ItemNumber - varchar(20)
      '10.01.02' , -- FromBin - varchar(10)
      'Rework' , -- ToBin - varchar(10)
      25  -- Qty - int
    ); 

INSERT  INTO #TransfersNeeded
    ( ItemNumber ,
      FromBin ,
      ToBin ,
      Qty
    )
VALUES  ( '850-001-003' , -- ItemNumber - varchar(20)
      '14.01.12' , -- FromBin - varchar(10)
      'Rework' , -- ToBin - varchar(10)
      25  -- Qty - int
    ); 


SELECT  *
FROM    #Adjustments_in;
SELECT  *
FROM    #Adjustments_out;
SELECT  *
FROM    #TransfersNeeded;
```

Where it looks at Adjustments_in and compares it to Adjustments_out  then reconciles the three bins 
Since the company is going to adjust IN a QTY of 50 to the "Rework" bin and adjust OUT a sum of 50 from multiple Bins. What we are trying to do is identify the items where a BIN to BIN  transfer can be done instead to prevent any financial impact for same item out and then back in. Currently this processes is done manually line by line via Excel. It is extremely time consuming and is open to human errors.
I can get this to work with a 1:1 relationship between the two tables but not a 1:N or N:1  anyone have an Idea if SQL can do this?